# How can I add acknowledgements on the title page as a numbered footnote?

Tags: numbering, footnotes, titles

I was asked to add acknowledgements to the right of the author name as the first footnote. (So the footnote should be numbered as "1" but for some reason it only shows asterisk "*".)

Could anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno,pdftex]{article}
\title{AAAAA}
\author{BBBBB\footnote{CCCCC} \\DDDDD University }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
EEEEEE
\end{abstract}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in the edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 12):

The standard classes locally redefine footnote internals to use symbols and different formatting, so that `\thanks` works (which is really just `\footnote` in disguise.

It would be possible to undo those redefinitions but just for a one off note I'd simply avoid the issue as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno,pdftex]{article}
\title{AAAAA}

\author{BBBBB\textsuperscript{1}\\DDDDD University }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
EEEEEE
\end{abstract}
\footnotetext[1]{CCC}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, it's so simple and it totally worked! Thank you so much. And thank you for the tip for displaying codes too.

Answer (score 9):

The `article` class defines `\footnote` in the title part as `\thanks` and numbers it with symbols (this is customary in many journals).

You can revert the policy by patching the `\maketitle` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@fnsymbol}{\@arabic}{}{}
% \patchcmd{\maketitle}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{AAAAA}
\author{BBBBB\thanks{CCCCC} \\DDDDD University }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
EEEEEE
\end{abstract}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Uncomment the second `\patchcmd` line if you need that the successive footnotes start from 2. With the `%` in place the first footnote in the document body will be numbered 1.

The `pdftex` option is usually not needed (I recommend *not* specify it).

Comment: yes perhaps that's simpler than mine so +1, I was thinking you'd have to undo more. I suppose main difference is if you'd want the \thanks usage _and_ the numbered footnote.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One should know whether successive footnotes must be numbered starting from 2. In this case some more patching is needed.