# Titlepage with thanks to following page

Tags: footnotes, titles

### Titlepage

I wrote a titlepage like usual but I have supervisors from different universities. In order to provide the reader this information, I thought of writing the following possibilities:

1. Using standard footnotes

   ```
   Prof. A\footnote{University A}, Prof. B\footnote{University B}
   ```

This worked perfectly, except for the fact that the footnote was on the titlepage. This looked strange to have a footnote on the titlepage.

2. After that thought of using `\thanks{University xy}` but with this no footnotes appear at all.
3. In the end, I found a [similar question on stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/). It makes use of the commands
   `\textsuperscript{1}` and `\footnotetext[1]{University xy}`. This worked best as I can write the footnote text on the following page.

The third version as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final,onecolumn,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    {\large under the supervision of}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Dr. A\textsuperscript{1}}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Prof. B\textsuperscript{1}}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Prof. C\textsuperscript{2}}
  \end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\footnotetext[1]{University A}
\footnotetext[2]{University B}
\end{document}
```

### Question

How can I still provide hyperlinks to the footnotes? Or maybe more general what is the LaTeX-way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is using the commands `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` to add manually hyper-links into your document. The `hyperref` package is necessary.

To add a target use: `\hypertarget{label}{target caption}`

To add a link use: `\hyperlink{label}{link caption}`

Your first two pages become:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final,onecolumn,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    {\large under the supervision of}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Dr. A\textsuperscript{\hyperlink{uniA}{1}}}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Prof. B\textsuperscript{\hyperlink{uniA}{1}}}\vskip 1mm%
    {\large Prof. C\textsuperscript{\hyperlink{uniB}{2}}}
  \end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\footnotetext[1]{\hypertarget{uniA}{University A}}
\footnotetext[2]{\hypertarget{uniB}{University B}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An improvement of the alignment was desirable to me by applying the answer to [Ryan Reich's question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/).