# Footnote in title appears as symbols (want arabic numbers instead)

Tags: footnotes, titles

- I'm using Overleaf to prepare a LaTeX template. For that, I would have to use footnotes in the title, but when I use footnotes in the title they show up as symbols instead of numbers.
- When I use footnotes in body text, they appear as numbers and start at 1. Apparently, the footnotes used in the title and body text don't seem to be in sync with each other.
- For example, the following code is a simple example to demonstrate
  the issue I'm facing,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=6in,
   paperwidth=5in,
   top=10mm,
   bottom=20mm,
   left=10mm,
   right=10mm]{geometry}

   
\begin{document}
\title{This is my title\footnote{Just a note.}}   
\maketitle
Hello\footnote{World}
\end{document}
```

And the output that I see is,
[image: Footnotes are not synced]

Here, I expect that in the title the footnote will be marked as 1 and in the body as 2 and so on. I've tried various ways found on the web, but none seem to work. Your support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: I removed some tags that have nothing to do with the problem/question and slightly modified the title to be more helpful (IMHO) fur future users. Thanks for promoting a code example, this is helpful.

Comment: Promoting = providing :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if your question is an exact duplicate of [How can I add acknowledgements on the title page as a numbered footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62447). The linked duplicate offers *TWO* good answers and I show here only *ONE of the TWO* answers (from user `egreg`).

```
\documentclass{article}

% Copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62447
% --- ---
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@fnsymbol}{\@arabic}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\maketitle}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}{}
  \makeatother
% --- ---

\begin{document}
\title{This is my title\footnote{Just a note.}}   
\maketitle
Hello\footnote{World}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following your solution, I was able to resolve my issue. Thanks once again.